# Sampled loss in tf 1.4 seq2seq tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, softmax

Can anyone tell me, why in the seq2seq tutorial of tf 1.4 at https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/tree/tf-1.4
they don't use a sampled softmax loss? In their model they have a vocabulary of 40000 entries and only use a reduced sum of `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to get their training loss..

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion sampled softmax works for training only, when the tensorflow knows which classes are negative and it doesn't calculate loss for all the classes but few sampled negative classes and positive class. 
While for NMT, we would like to ultimately get predictions, in which case sampling would hurt the performance. 
Moreover, 40000 entries are not so bad in case of softmax.

Comment: Sure, sampling should only be used during training and a normal softmax during prediction. Sampling should boost training even for 40000 entries. But my question was, why did they used a sampled softmax in an older tutorial, but in the current one they don‘t use it. The number of entries in both tutorials is the same.